# On Click of Approve Button Unable to get model data from the razor-pages form

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am trying to pass the **ListOfUserModel** data **to** class(*UserRequests.cshtml.cs*) **from** the rajor page(*UserRequests.cshtml*) but it always goes to error function of ajax and prompts the alert box. I am trying to pass the records of the specific row on click of APPROVE button to the class. Can anyone please help me to understand what I am doing wrong here?

**Sample HTML Page**
[image]

**UserRequests.cshtml**

```
@page
@model UserRequestsModel
@{
    Layout = "~/Pages/Shared/_LayoutAdmin.cshtml";
}

<h5>Users Requests</h5>
<br>

<table id="usersTable" class="table table-dark" style="width: 100%;">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Company Email</th>
      <th style="width:20%">Approve/Deny</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
      @foreach(var user in Model.userList)
      {
      <tr>
      <td>@user.id</td>
      <td class="tdName">@user.Name</td>
      <td class="tdCompanyEmail">@user.CompanyEmail</td>
      <td>
        <button type="submit" class="btnApprove btn btn-success">Approve</button>
      </td>
      <td>
        <button type="submit" class="btnDeny btn btn-danger">Deny</button>
      </td>
      </tr>
      }
  </tbody>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(".btnApprove").click(function () {
        var ListOfUserModel = new Array();
        var row = $(this).closest('tr');
        var Name = row.find('.tdName').text();
        var CompanyEmail = row.find('.tdCompanyEmail').text();

        var UserModel = {};
        UserModel.Name = Name;
        UserModel.CompanyEmail = CompanyEmail;

        ListOfUserModel.push(UserModel);

        $.ajax({
            url: "/Admin/UserRequests",
            type: 'post',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            headers: { "RequestVerificationToken": $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val() },
            data: JSON.stringify(ListOfUserModel),
            success: function (data) {
                alert("Users Data Submitted Successfully");
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("SOME PROB.");
            }
        });
    });


</script>
```

**UserRequests.cshtml.cs**

```
using Tool.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;

namespace Tool.Pages.Admin
{
    public class UserRequestsModel : PageModel
    {
        [BindProperty]
        public UserModel NewUser { get; set; }

        public List<UserModel> userList = new List<UserModel>();
       

        public void OnGet()
        {
        }

        public IActionResult OnPost([FromBody]IEnumerable<UserModel> ListOfUserModel)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

**UserModel.cs**

```
namespace Tool.Models
{
    public class UserModel
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string? Name { get; set; }    
        public string? CompanyEmail { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Jquery ajax method error callback can receive some parameters. `error: function (xhr, status, error) { }`. Alert or console log these parameters to see what error you get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have used the value of `__RequestVerificationToken` `input` in your header, but this input is not present in your html code, and you receive an error due to not sending `anti forgery token`, just put the following code in a part of your `UserRequests.cshtml` File

```
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
```

more info: [What is Request Verification](https://www.learnrazorpages.com/security/request-verification)

Comment: Thank You so much for helping with the issue that too with proper explanation. I added @Html.AntiForgeryToken() and it worked successfully. But it's strange that i was doing the similar thing in my other form and was not making use of this token and still the response was getting successful there.

Comment: When you use `asp-action` attributes in the `form` tag
`AntiForgeryToken` is created automatically and you don't need to add it manually But you don't have a form with this specification, so you have to add `AntiForgeryToken` manually